# vector push_back shows absurd result

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, operator-overloading, push-back

I am trying to make a vector out of several integers by overloading the operator << and conversion operator.
However, when I test my code, I observe some absurd results.

The printed output should be 1 2 3 4.

But it actually print out something like this: 28495936 0 3 4.

The first two elements (e.g, 1 and 2) that were supposed to be pushed into the vector is lost or polluted.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me to figure it out the reason behind this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class make_vector {
public:
    typedef make_vector<T> my_type;
    my_type& operator<<(const T& val)
    {
        data_.push_back(val);
        return *this;
    }
    operator std::vector<T>&()
    {
        return  this->data_;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;
};


int main() {
    std::vector<int>&  A2 = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = A2.begin(); it != A2.end(); ++it)        
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are binding a lvalue reference to a temporary:

```
std::vector<int>&  A2 = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

Note that, as @T.C. mentions in comments, it is your conversion operator that enables this. Without it the statement above would be invalid C++.

The issue with your code is that after this line, `A2` refers to a defunct object.

It seems to me you don't want to use a reference:

```
std::vector<int>  A2 = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

Comment: I see the problem now. It helps! Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: You don't need an extension for this to compile, thanks to the poorly designed `operator std::vector<T>&()`. It should really be ref-qualified; and `operator<<` should probably also have two ref-qualified overloads so that you preserve the value category.

Comment: @T.C. I had completely missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a dangling reference here.  It references a temporary.

```
std::vector<int>&  A2 = make_vector<int>()....
```

You have two options:

You can **copy** the temp into a new, local variable.

```
std::vector<int>  A2 = make_vector<int>()....
```

<strike>Or **use a `const` ref**.  C++ grants a special rule to allow const references to extend the lifetime of a temporary.</strike>

```
const std::vector<int>&  A2 = make_vector<int>()....
```

Comment: const ref won't work. You are binding to the return value of a member function, rather than the temporary directly; that doesn't extend the lifetime.

Comment: @T.C. I never knew that.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Your `make_vector` is badly designed and dangerous to use. You made it convertible to `std::vector<T>&` referring to its `vector` member, even if the `make_vector` object is a temporary. This is a dangling reference waiting to happen, since with this setup the compiler won't complain when you do things like

```
std::vector<int>&  A2 = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

because everything in this line is perfectly valid. Except that it leaves `A2` a dangling reference as the `make_vector` temporary - and the vector it contains - gets destroyed at the `;`. Ouch.

A better design would ref-qualify and overload your `operator<<` and the conversion function:

```
my_type& operator<<(const T& val) &
{
    data_.push_back(val);
    return *this;
}
my_type&& operator<<(const T& val) &&
{
    data_.push_back(val);
    return std::move(*this);
}

operator std::vector<T>&() &
{
    return  this->data_;
}

operator std::vector<T>() &&
{
    return  std::move(this->data_);
}
```

First, we make only lvalue `make_vector`s convertible to an lvalue reference to the underlying vector, since this is probably safe. For rvalue `make_vector`s, such as temporaries, we make the conversion function return the vector by value by moving from the underlying vector.

Second, we overload `operator<<` to preserve the value category of the `make_vector` object it is invoked on - it returns an lvalue reference if invoked on an lvalue, and an rvalue reference if invoked on an rvalue. This way, `make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4` remains an rvalue.

Now errors like `std::vector<int>&  A2 = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;` won't compile, while both

```
std::vector<int> A2 = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

and

```
const std::vector<int> & A2 = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

will and both are safe. (In the second case, the const reference binds to the temporary returned by `operator std::vector<int>()`, which extends the lifetime of the temporary.)

Comment: T.C., I really appreciate your answer. There is enough information for me to digest and learn now. I will make sure that I can vote this answer up after I gain enough reputation later.

Comment: should the first conversion function be changed to operator std::vector<T>() & ?

Comment: @user1487243 Not needed; the point is that when the object is an lvalue, returning a reference is safe.